# How to get details of a document with its GUID - facing error "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: document-library, caml-query, guid

I am trying to get the document details of a document with its GUID, but error says "Value does not fall within the expected range."

```
query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='Recursive'>" + _
"<Query>" + _
 "<Where>" + _
 "<eq>" + _
"<FieldRef Name=""GUID""/>" + _
"<Value Type='Guid'>" + _
"26V2766C-3563-41F3-9970-0EC245695014" + _
"</Value>" + _
"</eq>" + _
"</Where>" + _
"</Query>" + _
"<ViewFields>" + _
"<FieldRef Name='ID' />" + _
"<FieldRef Name='URL' />" + _
 "</ViewFields>" + _
"</View>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 string guid = "put-your-guid-here";
    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();

query.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId'/><Value Type='Guid'>{0}</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>", guid);
```

Note that you need to reference the field by internal name, which is `UniqueId`. You also have XML syntax errors there. Remember that it's case sensitive and `<eq>` is not the same as `<Eq>`.

Comment: Can I download a document with GUID itself from my vb.net code rather than passing the URL in the request ?

Comment: Check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125229/get-library-and-folder-from-document-guid-c