# How do I get List from RootFolder in CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have a utility function to copy documents from one folder to another folder in SharePoint Online using C#/CSOM. It works well for subfolders, but I am having issues with RootFolders for libraries.

For example, this will get the root list for a subfolder. I use the return List for other tasks like copying content types, fields, and other configuration for the copied documents:

```
public static List Foo(Folder bar)
{
     return bar.ListItemAllFields.ParentList;
}
```

Problem is, when I pass a List.RootFolder object to this function (which uses the Folder class), there is an error because ListItemAllFields is null. The question is how do I get the parent list with just the Folder as a parameter if the folder's ListItemAllFields property is null? This does not work:

```
public static void FooBar(List list)
{
     List self = Foo(list.RootFolder); 
}
public static List Foo(Folder bar)
{
     return bar.ListItemAllFields.ParentList;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have written utility for SPO site to copy entire library folders and files. The syntax I am using as follows

```
List srcLst = srcCtx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SourceListTitle);
var srcLibRootFolder = srcLst.RootFolder;
srcCtx.Load(srcLibRootFolder);
srcCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

After Load operation, I am getting root folder object.

Comment: Thanks! But I am trying to do the opposite - I am trying to get a List object from a RootFolder.

Comment: Can you verify this link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125229/get-library-and-folder-from-document-guid-c see it might help to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

If you have the URL of the folder, you can use `Web.GetList()`, and pass the url in:

```
var list = ctx.Web.GetList(folder.ServerRelativeUrl);
```

Not sure if this is viable in your scenario, but it's one option.

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getlist.aspx) for `Web.GetList()`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. The way I have it set up is to not accept Web as a parameter. I am doing this so I can re-use the function more easily. I tried doing var ctx =
 (ClientContext)folder.Context; List list = ctx.Web.GetListByUrl(url), but folder.Context could reference a context created for the root web of the site collection or another parent web. Therefore, ClientContext.Web may not actually refer to the same Web as the folder.

Comment: I'm not seeing a way to get a `List` instance from the root folder.  I can see ways to obtain the list, if you have a `ClientContext`.  The way above is one such way, another would be to use the property bag (you can get the list id and name there).  Sorry I'm unable to help