# Is there any property available in CSOM which would indicate that a list is using a custom new/edit/display form?

Tags: development, csom, custom-form, .net

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to check to see if a list is using a non-default custom form via CSOM? I'm thinking of looking for any forms that weren't created at the time of the list's creation or created by the default user if there's nothing more direct, but I'm hoping to avoid loading every file in every list (non-library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I'm just going to see if the list has more than 3 forms in the list.Forms property as I'm hoping no one made the mistake of deleting an OOTB list form. If this doesn't hold up, you can use the form collection to filter out the files in the list and download each file. On each file, there is a [CustomizedPageStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.customizedpagestatus.aspx) property which can be checked. The value is None or 0 for every custom form I've seen thus far, and it is Uncustomized or 1 for every OOTB list form I've seen thus far. It's surprisingly, to me, very quick. It also includes custom view pages (e.g., views which have additional web parts added).

My code sample:

```
    context.Load(list.RootFolder.Files, f => f.Where(f => (int)f.CustomizedPageStatus != 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the URL of displayform dynamically by making use of "ParentList" property.

```
   currentItem.ParentList.get_defaultDisplayFormUrl()
   currentItem.ParentList.get_defaultEditFormUrl()
```

Once you have it, you can validate if its OOB page or custom one.

Comment: Many of our sites have renamed the OOTB forms amd reused the default urls in order to make use of a code library. The OOTB forms have a property indicating which type of page it is, but I believe you lose that property on custom forms.

Comment: Another comment - some of the custom forms exist to supplement the default forms, so this would also prevent me from finding those.

Answer (score 1):

From CSOM? Probably. :-)  There is from REST. This will get you form files properties:

```
http://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/RootFolder/Files
```

and then:
    d.results[0].TimeLastModified

There is an example to get you to the RootFolder using CSOM here:

[How do I get List from RootFolder in CSOM?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216940/how-do-i-get-list-from-rootfolder-in-csom)

Comment: This was my last option, but I guess I was hoping to find a more direct property on the list or content types even if it was in the xml itself.

Comment: @Dinerdo   Not that I know of.