# Get parent document library for the folder using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I need to access the parent document library for the folder. I am having the selected folder GUID by which I am loading it.

```
 _spFolder = _contex.Web.GetFolderById(Guid.Parse(_folderId));
```

But I also need the Document library where the folder is located. How can I get it using _spFolder object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I recall it one of the properties on a SPFolder object is the Document Library.
This might be what you are looking for:
[Get Library and Folder from document guid (C#)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125229/get-library-and-folder-from-document-guid-c)